# Получить значение элементов с одинаковым классом

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как лучше в JavaScript идентифицировать действие 'Скрыть/Показать' для  в след конструкции:

```
   <div id="one">
      <span class="clickClass">Скрыть</span>
   </div>
   <div id="two">
      <span class="clickClass">Показать</span>
   </div>
```

Классы у `<span>` одинаковые.
При клике на `span` нужно получить значение, по которому потом будет производиться какое-то действие.

Мне нужно сделать 2 кнопки. При нажатии на Скрыть, скрывается текущий `div id='one'`, показывается второй `id='two'`. Во втором `div` есть кнопка показать. При нажатии скрывается текущий `div id='two'`, показывается `id='one'`

Comment: что значит _значение, по которому потом будет производиться какое-то действие._?

Comment: @Grundy, Значение html внутри span.

Comment: @Grundy, Мне нужно сделать 2 кнопки. При нажатии на Скрыть, скрывается текущий div id='one', показывается второй id='two'. Во втором div есть кнопка показать. При нажатии скрывается текущий div id='two', показывается id='one'

Comment: вот всё, что вы только что написали, добавьте в свой вопрос посредством его редактирования. P.S. то, что вам надо получить, называется не значением, а содержимым

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
   x=document.getElementsByClassName('clickClass');
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
 {

x[i].addEventListener("click", function(){


  if ( this.innerHTML == 'Скрыть' ) {
 
  document.getElementById("one").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("two").style.display="inline";
  } 
  else if (this.innerHTML == 'Показать' ) {
  document.getElementById("one").style.display="inline";
  document.getElementById("two").style.display="none";
   
                                          
}});}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <span class="clickClass">Скрыть</span>
   </div>
   <div id="two">
  <span class="clickClass">Показать</span>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("clickClass");

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){document.getElementById('x').innerHTML  = this.innerHTML});
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
      <span class="clickClass">Скрыть</span>
   </div>
   <div id="two">
      <span class="clickClass">Показать</span>
   </div>
  <p id="x"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

  $('.clickClass').click(function(){
    if ( $(this).text() == 'Скрыть' ) {
      // ваши действия
    } else if ( $(this).text() == 'Показать' ) {
      // ваши действия
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но нужно на классическом JavaScript без использования библиотеки jQuery,